# Javascript : allow function to return two string value

Tags: coffeescript, decimal

I have a JavaScript function that return a comma character for decimal input :

```
getLocalDecimalSeparator: ->
    $translate.instant( 'numbers.decimal_separator' )
```

the translate is defined like that :

```
numbers:
      decimal_separator:   ","
```

I want my inputs accept dot character also for decimal numbers, I thought about adding an regExp or return the two characters in one function.

I tried this :

```
getLocalDecimalSeparator: ->
    ['.' , ',']
```

but it didn't work !

Comment: "It didn't work" isn't a very useful description. What error are you getting? Where is the `getLocalDecimalSeparator` used?

Comment: Hey @noun7, @caffeinated-tech is exactly right. Your question is not answerable based on the information provided. Without some information about how `getLocalDecimalSeparator` is being used there's no way for anyone to tell you how to make this work. But in general I would guess that whatever is calling `getLocalDecimalSeparator` is expecting a single character, not an array, and that you won't be able to get the pair `'.', ','` to work without changing the assumptions being made by the calling method.